# How to handle RDD objects to collection objects

Tags: apache-spark

I am having problem in conversion of `RDD` objects to `collection` objects, is there any logic how to do it ?

row sample : `11-06-05-2016,Euro,EUR,0.803`

code:

```
val exRDD = sc.textFile(exchangeRatesPath).cache()

exRDD.map(l => l).map(rec => ( rec.split(",")(0) -> rec.split(",")(3).toDouble ) )
```

what is my mistake here ?

Comment: What do you mean you want to convert it to a collection object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood from your question, you want to create `collections` of `Map(date -> amount)`. But you were surprised of getting `Tuple2(String, Double)` collection.

If I have understood you correct then you can achieve what you require by doing

```
val exRDD = sc.textFile("exchangeRatesPath").cache()

exRDD.map(line => line.split(",")).map(rec => scala.collection.mutable.HashMap(rec(0) -> rec(3).toDouble))
```

Comment: Thank yo for your prompt reply ....but why mutable HashMap here ? why not immutable ? Unfortunately it is not getting desired results.....type mismatch; found : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Double]] required: Map[String,Double]

Comment: Its your choice to choose mutable or immutable. you will be able to change mutables but you won't be able to modify the immutable hashmaps. You must be trying to assign the output to Map[String.Double] . Can you illustrate on what line you are getting that error so that i can help you

Comment: Thank you Ramesh, error is on same line in ide         exRDD.map(line => line.split(",")).map(rec => scala.collection.mutable.HashMap(rec(0) -> rec(3).toDouble)) .....i am suppose to return  Map[String,Double] from this block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns just `Tuple2[String, Double]` If you are willing to get `Map[String, Double]`. you need to do

```
exRDD.map(
    rec =>
      Map(rec.split(",")(0) -> rec.split(",")(3).toDouble))
```

Note: I think `exRDD.map(l => l)` this is not required because it is not doing anything except returning a line through iterating it

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you so much sir , sir one issue , I need read records of file and split by "," to get specific columns and need to return it in a specific case class RDD , i.e. RDD[BidItem] , sir please help me I have no clue how to go about it.....how to return case class first , if each row as one case class it should be List[BidItem] but here i need return RDD[BidItem], how can i return it ...? i am very new to spark and scala , so no clue ....your help is hightly appriciated.

Comment: you can create it as     val result = exRDD.map(
      rec =>{
        val value = rec.split(",")
        BidItem(value(0),value(1),value(2),value(3).toDouble)
      })

with case class as 
case class BidItem(date: String, curr: String, cont: String, rate: Double)

Comment: sir one more question i am getting scala> val nonErroniousBidsMap = rawBids.filter(line => !(line(2).contains("ERROR_")))
nonErroniousBidsMap: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[70] at filter at <console>:33  ......but each RDD List has one string in it , how can i get RDD[string] i.e. that list one element out ?

Comment: Thank you so much Shankar sir, I need to get other record rows which do not contain ERROR

Comment: You can filter out the lines that contains ERROR as
exRDD.filter(!_.contains("ERROR"))

Comment: Sir Can you help me with this problem too.                                                             https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529162/how-to-get-rddliststring-to-string-and-split-it