# How to get RDD[List[String]] to String and split it

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I have below scenario , when I need to get the lines from list and split it.

```
scala> var nonErroniousBidsMap = rawBids.filter(line => !(line(2).contains("ERROR_") || line(5) == null || line(5) == ""))
nonErroniousBidsMap: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[108] at filter at <console>:33

scala> nonErroniousBidsMap.take(2).foreach(println)
List(0000002, 15-04-08-2016, 0.89, 0.92, 1.32, 2.07, , 1.35)
List(0000002, 11-05-08-2016, 0.92, 1.68, 0.81, 0.68, 1.59, , 1.63, 1.77, 2.06, 0.66, 1.53, , 0.32, 0.88, 0.83, 1.01)

scala> val transposeMap = nonErroniousBidsMap.map( rec => ( rec.split(",")(0) + "," + rec.split(",")(1) + ",US" + "," + rec.split(",")(5) ) )
<console>:35: error: value split is not a member of List[String]
     val transposeMap = nonErroniousBidsMap.map( rec => ( rec.split(",")(0) + "," + rec.split(",")(1) + ",US" + "," + rec.split(",")(5) ) )
                                                              ^
```

I am getting an error as showed above.
Can you please help me how to solve this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please put your code in the code format to make it easier to read. If you don't know how, you can just highlight the code and press Cmd+K or Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `rec` is `List[String]` - which does not have a `split(String)` method (as the compiler correctly warns). It looks like you're assuming your records are comma-separated Strings, but in fact they're not (when you call `println` on each one of them, they are printed with comma separators simply because that's how `List.toString` behaves).

You can simply remove all the calls to `split(",")` and get what you want:

```
nonErroniousBidsMap.map(rec => rec.head + "," + rec(1) + ",US" + "," + rec(5))
```

Or even more elegantly, using Scala's String Interpolation:

```
nonErroniousBidsMap.map(rec => s"${rec.head},${rec(1)},US,${rec(5)}")
```

Comment: Thank you so much guru,  you saved my day...thank you so much...Above rec items i mapped to a Case class called Bid ,   Each one of the below holds Bid records i.e transUS , transMX and transCA.......and when am returning from my method RDD[Bid] ....but when return ::   val transAll = transUS.union(transMX).union(transCA)  ....it is giving an error " type mismatch found : Unit required RDD[Bid] " , so how to return RDD[Bid] from above union. ??? please help me.

Comment: sir i have similar problem as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44536380/type-mismatch-found-unit-expected-rddxyz , can you please help me.