# type mismatch found : Unit expected : RDD[XYZ...]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm getting type mismatch error for below scenario

```
//scores sample file  
0000006,Danny,6.2  
0000002,Danny,7.0
```

Code.

```
 case class Person(id: String, dob: String, country: String, score: Double) 

 def getResultRecords(persons: RDD[List[String]]): RDD[Person] = {

   val personUS = persons.map(rec => Person(rec.head, rec(1),"US"), java.lang.Double.parseDouble(cpg.getOrElse(rec.head,"0").toString())
   val personMX = persons.map(rec => Person(rec.head, rec(1),"MX"),java.lang.Double.parseDouble(cpg.getOrElse(rec.head,"0").toString()))
   val personAll = personUS.union(personMX)
   //return personAll
}//Getting an error saying " type mismach found : Unit expected : RDD[Person]"
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I fix it?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

In Spark, [transformations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations) are **lazy**. You need to execute an **[action](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions)** returning an `RDD[Person]`. Otherwise, your function won't return anything. That's why the Type Mismatch error.

Comment: Spark's laziness has absolutely nothing to do with this - it doesn't come into play at compile time at all.

Comment: @TzachZohar, have you tried to reproduce the error? Because I did and if you don't put back that return statement at the end, or use an action like `personAll.cache()` the compiler throws that type mismatch exception.

Comment: Adding the return statement (with or without the `return` keyword) solves the issue, as the other answer suggests; Returning the correct value is not a Spark "action", nor is `cache` (it's a transformation) - both resolve the issue indeed (because `cache` also returns the `RDD[Person]`) yet both have nothing to do with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

YOur method signature is `def getResultRecords(persons: RDD[List[String]]): RDD[Person]`; that means the method should return an instance of `RDD[Person]`.

However, the last line of that same method says - `val personAll =  personUS.union(personMX)` - which returns nothing.

Uncomment `return personAll` line - and this will erase your exception.

Also, I found some issue with your syntax.

Here's is your code snippet.

```
case class Person(id: String, dob: String, country: String, score: Double) 

def getResultRecords(persons: RDD[List[String]]): RDD[Person] = {

  val personUS = persons.map(rec => Person(rec.head, rec(1),"US", java.lang.Double.parseDouble(cpg.getOrElse(rec.head,"0").toString()))
  val personMX = persons.map(rec => Person(rec.head, rec(1),"MX",java.lang.Double.parseDouble(cpg.getOrElse(rec.head,"0").toString()))
  val personAll =  personUS.union(personMX)
  return personAll
}
```

An extra parenthesis `)` is given here - `Person(rec.head, rec(1),"US"`.
And `return` statement was commented out.

Comment: Thanks you , may syntax problem is due to copy paste error ....actual problem is it is returning Unit ,even i remove return personAll statement removed ....  Moreover when I say       scoresRDD.map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1), "US", p(2).toDouble)).first()     It gives an error like this            type mismatch; found : com.epam.hubd.spark.scala.core.homework.Person required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[com.epam.hubd.spark.scala.core.homework.Person]              sir can you help me

Comment: Try with the code snippet that I added in my answer.

Sorry for now, but I am in transit; not able to use skype. :(